# How can I get the value of a property of type multiple union interface types?

Tags: angular, typescript, typeguards

I have the following code:

```
  const arrayFromForm: IFirst[] | ISecond[] | IThird[]; // = ... it's initialized
  const arrayDB: IFirst[] | ISecond[] | IThird[]; // = ... it's initialized
  const entitiesFromDb = arrayDB.filter(
    (entity: IFirst | ISecond | IThird) =>
      !(arrayFromForm.map(({ id }) => id))
      .includes(entity.id)
  );
```

And it gives me 1 error: `"The map expression is not callable"`.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that this is because it doesn't know that there is a property named `id` in all of the interfaces in the union.

---

I've used a type guard before, but I think you can create a type guard only between 2 types in an union, because you have to return a boolean?

I want to solve this problem with typescript (user-defined type guard, typeof, instanceof, etc.), but I'm not sure that this is possible, isn't it? `instanceof` type guards can't be created for interfaces, right?
What's a *good* solution here?

---

EDIT: I've just solved the problem with an interface with the properties that the interfaces in the union have in common and I just changed the type union with the new interface. This is not very good solution as I would want to use specific methods/properties in the different interfaces that I would've had in the type union.

So I'm not deleting the question, because it's still helpful to know if there is a such thing as an user-defined type guards for type unions with more than 2 types in them.

Comment: find my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a known issue in Typescript. See [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390).

But for now you can do this:

```
const arrayFromForm: IFirst[] | ISecond[] | IThird[]; // = ... it's initialized
const entitiesFromDb = arrayDB.filter(
  (entity: IFirst | ISecond | IThird) =>
    !(arrayFromForm as {id: number}[]).map(item => item.id).includes(entity.id) // Pay attention to the brackets
);
```

We cast the `arrayFromForm` as just one appropriate type, instead of a union of types. This is close to the solution you came up with but I think it's easier to maintain it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives me the following error: `This filter expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.` on the very first filter: arrayDB.filter(...)

Comment: whats the type of `arrayDB`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I applied the same logic for the array and it worked. (arrayDB as {id: number}[])

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
const elementsIds = arrayFromForm.filter(arrItem => arrItem.id).map((item)=>item.id); 
  const entitiesFromDb = arrayDB.filter(
    (entity: IFirst | ISecond | IThird) =>
      !elementsIds.includes(entity.id)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives me a similar error: `This filter expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.` on the first filter (first line)